# How to create a new column that is the sum of the number of columns from a specific range that meet multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, conditional-statements

.I have a dataframe that looks similar to this (except the number of `Visit` and `Deliv` columns goes up to `Visit_12` and `Deliv 12` and there are several hundred clients - I have simplified it here)

```
Client   Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Deliv_1  Deliv_2  Deliv_3 Key_DT
Client_1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-03-29 No       Yes      Yes     2018-01-15
Client_2 2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10 Yes      Yes      No      2018-01-25
Client_3 2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10 Yes      Yes      Yes     2018-04-15
Client_4 2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10 Yes      No       Yes     2018-02-25
Client_5 2018-04-02 2018-04-07 2018-04-20 Yes      No       Yes     2018-04-01
```

I want to create a new column called `Vis_sum` that shows, for all clients with a `Key_DT` after `2018-01-20` but before `2018-03-25`, the sum of the number of visits from `Visit_1` to `Visit_3` that (i) come after the `Key_DT` in the same row, (ii) come before `2018-03-25` and (iii) have a `Yes` in the associated `Deliv` column (e.g. `Deliv_1` is associated with `Visit_1`). It should look like this

```
Client   Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Deliv_1  Deliv_2  Deliv_3 Key_DT     Vis_sum
Client_1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-03-29 No       Yes      Yes     2018-01-15 0
Client_2 2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10 Yes      Yes      No      2018-01-25 1
Client_3 2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10 Yes      Yes      Yes     2018-04-15 0
Client_4 2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10 Yes      No       Yes     2018-02-25 1
Client_5 2018-04-02 2018-04-07 2018-04-20 Yes      No       Yes     2018-04-01 0
```

Please note - there is missing data in all columns, so this must be taken into account.

I have tried the following - but it didn't work. While the code for parts (i) and (ii) work when tried together, and the code for (iii) works on its own, when all of the code below is written, it returns `0` for every row in the column `Vis_sum`:

`df.loc[((df.Key_DT < '2018-03-25') & 
         (df.Key_DT >= '2018-01-20')), 'Vis_sum'] = ((df.filter(like='Visit_').gt(df.Key_DT,axis=0)) &                                                                                    (df.filter(like='Visit_').lt(pd.to_datetime('2018-03-25')).fillna(0).astype(bool)) &                                                                                (df.filter(like='Deliv_').eq('Yes'))).sum(1)`

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already?

Comment: (a) not with these extra conditions added, and (b) none of the solutions worked - most likely due to the lack of clarity in the question. I'm hoping by reframing the question the suggestions will be more likely to work - any ideas?

Comment: Could you also post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Good point - please see the edited question

Comment: What I would personally do(and I've had a dataset similar to this) is to melt my frames and create a tabular format to run analysis on, then you can use a groupby + cumcount to get your desired result. will have a play with your sample

Comment: p.s shouldn't `client 1` have Vis_sum of 1 as the `2nd Deliv` is after the `Key DT `and has a `yes`?

Comment: @Datanovice all that is true - except the Key_DT is not in the window (i.e. between 2018-01-20 and 2018-03-25), so the code does not apply. Good luck!

Comment: ah my bad, see my attempt below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar (very messy generated by a survey) dataset which I used `melt`, `merge` and a `groupby-transform-cumcount` to get my intended number

working with your assumption that your dataset is called df :

```
#First melt the DF and the unique visits (you'll have to do this for all your value_vars)    
df1 = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Client',value_vars=['Visit_1','Visit_2','Visit_3'],var_name='Visit',value_name='Visit Date')
print(df1.head(5))
Client  Visit   Visit Date
0   Client_1    Visit_1 2018-01-01
1   Client_2    Visit_1 2018-01-10
2   Client_3    Visit_1 2018-01-20
3   Client_4    Visit_1 2018-01-30
4   Client_5    Visit_1 2018-04-02
#lets do the same for the deliveries 
df2 = pd.melt(df,id_vars='Client',value_vars=['Deliv_1','Deliv_2','Deliv_3'],var_name='Delivery',value_name='Check')
```

after the melting we can merge your values back onto the tabular style df.

```
# Lets merge these and then put the Key_DT back on 
res = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Client')
res = pd.merge(res,df[['Client','Key_DT']],on='Client')
print(res.head(5))
        Client  Visit   Visit Date  Delivery    Check   Key_DT
0   Client_1    Visit_1 2018-01-01  Deliv_1 No  2018-01-15
1   Client_1    Visit_1 2018-01-01  Deliv_2 Yes 2018-01-15
2   Client_1    Visit_1 2018-01-01  Deliv_3 Yes 2018-01-15
3   Client_1    Visit_2 2018-01-20  Deliv_1 No  2018-01-15
4   Client_1    Visit_2 2018-01-20  Deliv_2 Yes 2018-01-15
```

lets filter by your conditions and do a count of the values by `Client`

```
s = res.loc[(res['Key_DT'] >= '2018-01-20') & (res['Key_DT'] <= '2018-03-25') & (res.Check == 'Yes')]
res['visit_sum'] = s.groupby(['Client','Visit'])['Check'].transform('cumcount')
res['visit_sum'] = res['visit_sum'].fillna(0)
print(res.loc[res['visit_sum'] > 0])
    Client  Visit   Visit Date  Delivery    Check   Key_DT  visit_sum
27  Client_4    Visit_1 2018-01-30  Deliv_1 Yes 2018-02-25  1.0
29  Client_4    Visit_1 2018-01-30  Deliv_3 Yes 2018-02-25  1.0
30  Client_4    Visit_2 2018-03-01  Deliv_1 Yes 2018-02-25  1.0
32  Client_4    Visit_2 2018-03-01  Deliv_3 Yes 2018-02-25  1.0
33  Client_4    Visit_3 2018-03-10  Deliv_1 Yes 2018-02-25  1.0
35  Client_4    Visit_3 2018-03-10  Deliv_3 Yes 2018-02-25  1.0
```

hopefully that *sort* of helps and puts you in the direction to get your intended result.

Comment: Awesome! I thought it might need some tinkering on your end but I'm glad it worked. Thanks for the green tick .

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote doesn't work because it doesn't know it should match `Visit_#` with `Deliv_#`. Try this instead:

```
df.loc[((df.Key_DT < '2018-03-25') & (df.Key_DT >= '2018-01-20')), 'Vis_sum'] = ((df.filter(like='Visit_').gt(df.Key_DT,axis=0)) & (df.filter(like='Visit_').lt(pd.to_datetime('2018-03-25'),axis=0).fillna(0).astype(bool)) & (df.filter(like='Deliv_').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('Deliv','Visit')).eq('Yes'))).sum(1)
```